# How to add delay before/during test (using supertest & jest) while waiting for dynamodb event to occur

Tags: node.js, amazon-dynamodb, jestjs, amazon-sns, supertest

I'm writing tests for a `Nodejs REST app in supertest & jest`, and can't figure out how to add a delay between two tests being executed.

I have two tests in sequence; the first calls an endpoint that sends an `SNS` message to `DynamoDB`, and the second checks that this message has arrived and saves some of the details for future tests. The second often fails because the `SNS` message hasn't had sufficient time to reach `DynamoDB`. I simply want to add some kind of delay or wait before the second test runs to accommodate this.

**The two tests are as follows:**

```
describe('User1 invite User2', () => {
    it('It should return OK and send message to User2', () => {
        return request.post('/room/' + room_id + '/invitation')
        .query({zone_id: zoneid, session_id: user1_session_id, user_id: user2_userid, token: room_token})
        .set('Authorization', user1_id_token)
        .expect(200)
    })
})


describe('User2 get invite message', () => {
    it('It should return OK with message details: room_id, room_token, user1_userid', () => {
        return request.get('/lobby/mailbox')
        .query({ session_id: user2_session_id })
        .set('Authorization', user2_id_token)
        .expect(200)
        .then((response) => {
            received_room_id = response.body.mailbox_message.room_id;
            received_room_token = response.body.mailbox_message.room_token;
            from_user = response.body.mailbox_message.sender_user_id;
            expect(received_room_id).toEqual(room_id);
            expect(from_user).toEqual(user1_userid);
        })
    })
})
```

I've tried changing the second test to `include async/await` like below but not sure if I'm missing something as it doesn't seem to be working.

```
describe('User2 get invite message', () => {
    it('It should return OK with message details: room_id, room_token, user1_userid', async () => {
        const response = await request.get('/lobby/mailbox')
            .query({ session_id: user2_session_id })
            .set('Authorization', user2_id_token)
            .expect(200);
        received_room_id = response.body.mailbox_message.room_id;
        received_room_token = response.body.mailbox_message.room_token;
        from_user = response.body.mailbox_message.sender_user_id;
        expect(received_room_id).toEqual(room_id);
        expect(from_user).toEqual(user1_userid);

    })
})
```

I've also tried `including .setTimeout()` in the request but that doesn't seem to work either.

Still relatively new to `nodejs` so apologies in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's usually a bad practice to have one test rely on the output of another test - in this case, you can't run the second test in isolation.

What about combining the tests into a single test? You could either put some [`Promise` based delay handler](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.delay.html) or some application-specific polling mechanism in between the separate steps to guarantee the functionality.